# How to integrate Sonar in Hudson?

Tags: exception, hudson, sonarqube, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Hudson 1.323 and tried with Sonar 1.4 and 2.0.1 plugin but in both cases getting the below exception. Can anyone suggest how it can be integrated?

```
FATAL:
hudson.model.Hudson.getDescriptorOrDie(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lhudson/model/Descriptor;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
hudson.model.Hudson.getDescriptorOrDie(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lhudson/model/Descriptor;
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarMaven.getDescriptor(SonarMaven.java:99)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.getMaven(Maven.java:153)  
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:233)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarMaven.executeMaven(SonarMaven.java:149)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.executeSonar(SonarPublisher.java:331)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.perform(SonarPublisher.java:292)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:480)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildStep(AbstractBuild.java:466)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildStep(AbstractBuild.java:454)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:146)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:438)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1140)  
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)  
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:93)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:122)
```

Comment: Seems version not compatible!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of Hudson that is not supported by the SonarQube plugin. Unfortunately, no more developments will be done on SonarQube plugin for Hudson.